# How to start text and image on the same baseline

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, geometry, grid-typesetting

I need text and images to start at the same level on each page.

With standard LaTeX settings the image seems to start a few points higher then a text. I believe this is due to `\topskip`. `\topskip=0pt` should solve the problem, but...

I have a MWE with package `geometry` where I settle the `\texthight` in two ways (both have disadvantages):

1. `textheight={190mm},heightrounded` which results in ragged bottom of the page (unacceptable)
2. `lines=40` which gives a proper bottom but there a text is slightly lower then the image (if now other solution the editor will accept this).

What to do to have both text and images start at the same level?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[draft,columns=1]{typogrid}
\topskip=0pt
\usepackage[a4paper,layoutsize={176mm,250mm},%
  layouthoffset={20mm},layoutvoffset={28.5mm},%
  textwidth={115mm},lines=40,%
  %textheight={190mm},heightrounded,%
  headsep={10pt},hcentering,vcentering]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{}
\end{document}
```

To Steven B. Segletes: This what I need
http://mleczko.students.wmi.amu.edu.pl/frame.png

This was done by Urlike's answer with +7pt

Comment: The value can be calculated, e.g.: `\newdimen\HeightOfM` and `\settoheight{\HeightOfM}{M}`. With standard fonts and class size option (`10pt`), the result is `6.83331pt`, close to `7pt`. Alternatively `\topskip` can be set to that height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image has a large height and so touch the top. Move it down (adapt the 6pt to your liking):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[draft,columns=1]{typogrid}
\topskip=0pt
\usepackage[a4paper,layoutsize={176mm,250mm},%
  layouthoffset={20mm},layoutvoffset={28.5mm},%
  textwidth={115mm},lines=40,%
  %textheight={190mm},heightrounded,%
  headsep={10pt},hcentering,vcentering]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
abc\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{}

\newpage
abc\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+6pt}{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, I dont't understand (`\dimexpr-\height`) but I see it works ;-) Is there any way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Ulrike's answer, but using the measure of the textheight itself (a so-called `\strut`).  With this approach, the top of the image can be adjusted from the top of the `\strutbox`, to get the image height separated from the page frame.

REVISED to reflect questioner's desire to have a gap between frame and image

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[draft,columns=1]{typogrid}
\topskip=0pt
\usepackage[a4paper,layoutsize={176mm,250mm},%
  layouthoffset={20mm},layoutvoffset={28.5mm},%
  textwidth={115mm},lines=40,%
  %textheight={190mm},heightrounded,%
  headsep={10pt},hcentering,vcentering]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
abc\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox+1pt]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{}}
\end{document}
```

Note the `+1pt` suffix to `\belowbaseline`'s optional argument will be the actual gap between the page frame and the top of the image. (In Ulrike's answer, the 6pt is the distance from the text baseline to the top of the letter's height)

[image]

Comment: it seems it's not working (I see the image at the top, compile with TeXLive 2013)

Comment: @pml I thought you wanted the top of the image aligned with the top top the text. Did I misunderstand? See edited answer above.

Comment: yes, but now the images touches the auxiliary frame, it should be a few point lower (since the text doesn't touch the frame) as in Ulrike's answer, but without guessing 6pt.

Comment: @pml: You can naturally use some font dependant value like 1ex or `0.7\ht\strutbox` instead of the 6pt (you probably should then call \normalfont\normalsize before the graphic). But you can't avoid to have to play around a bit to get the "best" value or factor as you want a position somewhere in the middle of the line - and this isn't a precise description of a position.

Comment: @pml I now understand your issue.  I have revised my answer to reflect the desire for a gap inside the page frame.  As Ulrike notes, however, that gap size is a font-dependent number, and will have to be selected by yourself.

Comment: perfect, I also edited my question and posted an image, unfortunately I can not accept two answers: I will accept the Ulrike's one since it doesn't invoke any additional package, but I do appreciate your answer and explanation. Regards